# Analytical solution to $e^{f(x^{\alpha+1})}=e^{f(x)}e^{f(x^\alpha)}$ other than $f(x)=\log{x^\lambda}$

Tags: functional-equations

The title is self explanatory... How can I prove (or find a counter example) that $f(x)=\log{x^\lambda}$ is the only analytical solution to this functional equation? Assumptions be made on $\alpha$, $f$ and $x$ belonging to real.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: $x^\lambda$ is not a solution...

Comment: How about $f(x^{a+1})=f(x)+f(x^a)$?

Comment: @Exodd Very sorry you're right, I forgot the log

Comment: Let y=xα

your equation can turn into f(xy)=f(x)+f(y), you can find many article about this Cauchy functional equation.

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash of course both equations are equivalent (only taking logarithms at both sides). I wrote it in the "weird" form of exponentials because to my eye it made it evident that f being the inverse function of exp was a solution.

Comment: @Abel Wong Funny fact: I made $x^{\alpha}=y$ in an attempt to solve the original problem :-)

Comment: Could it happen that $e^{f(x^{\alpha+1})}=e^{f(x)}e^{f(x^\alpha)}$ even if $e^{f(xy)}=e^{f(x)}e^{f(y)}$ fails for general $x$ and $y$?  Do we have to talk about $x^\alpha$ [or $x^\lambda$] where $x<0$  and $\alpha$ [or $\lambda$] is irrational?

Comment: @gudise. lol, I see.

Comment: Since there is some dense function solution for g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y), which is not linear( g(x)=ax). Take f(x)=log(g(x)). Then f(xy)=f(x)+f(y) is a solution not in $f(x)=logx$ form. You can see [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492/overview-of-basic-facts-about-cauchy-functional-equation) about the non-continuous solutions. Oh, can I log a dense function?, If I cannot, then your log function is the only solution.